# Powershell Error Catching With Static Member

Tags: powershell, static, operator-keyword, member

For reasons I'll not get into here, I'm being forced to use powershell to call and then populate a separate application. And to integrate it into a batch file, so powershell -command "& { }", which is already painful. I've got a while loop set call, check for the process ID to come up, then wait and call again if it hasn't come up yet.
The problem here is that afterwards I utilize a static member out of visualbasic to switch the focus to that application.
Namely, [microsoft.visualbasic.interaction]::AppActivate($hwnd) -- where $hwnd is the process ID of the application in question.

I hate to put anything like an artificial timer on there to wait for the application to finish loading, and I'd love to just put a while timer in there. But static member calls don't appear to support -erroraction or -errorvariable -- and the try {} catch {} appears to just ignore the error, as I was hoping to use it to trigger a flag to trigger the while loop to cycle again after a sleep of one second.

What other ways are there to catch errors out of a static member operator ::

Comment: Static members handle errors differently to cmdlets, but they should always trigger a try/catch regardless of `$ErrorActionPreference`. What error is being thrown that isn't getting trapped?

Comment: Disregard. The Try {} catch {} works great if I don't replace the final bracket with a close parenthesis. Just me being stupid and not watching my finale.

Comment: Ahah we've all been there, glad you got it sorted =)

Answer (score 0):

Disregard. The Try {} catch {} works great if I don't replace the final bracket with a close parenthesis.